# Backbone.js how to access a form value inside a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need to access a hidden form value from within a view:

```
I have tried this: form.getValue('user')
```

But I don't have access to the form object within the view:

My View:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#panel',

        events: {
            'submit #form': 'save'
        },// end of events
        save: function (ev) {
            var Details = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
            console.log(form.getValue('user'))

            var obj = new model();

            obj.save(Details, {
            success: function (obj) {

              },
            error: function (model, response) {
              console.log('error', model, response);
            }
            });


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the `form` variable coming from? The way it looks on the sample code makes it seem like a global variable, which would be bad news.

There are a couple of ways to get access to it. The easiest would be to look within the view's scope for your field:

```
save: function(ev) {
  var userVal = this.$('.user').val()
}
```

`this.$` is something that Backbone views have to clamp down jQuery's scope to just the DOM elements it represents, so you won't get anything outside of your view. Do note that the selector I used is `.user` which'll look for a CSS class, like on this:

```
<input type="text" class="user" id="whatever" />
```